# How to create a Hook_Schema for Fieldset Form?

Tags: forms, database

i have a form i would like to have the values submitted into a table in mysql database using hook_schema in a .install file. problem is i have no idea how to properly write it out being new to php  and all. i basically have a custom form with over 50 total field divided up into 3 different fieldsets displayed to user depending on checkbosed clicked. what is the best way to write a hook_schema to upload the submission values from my form into my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your schema already defined for a table in MySQL somewhere, did you already make it in like phpmyadmin? ... if so, the [Schema](http://www.drupal.org/project/schema) module will show you the exact PHP needed for hook_schema

I recommend:

- make a table in your drupal database using something like Navicat, phpmyadmin, mysql admin ... whatever. The table columns are your form field inputs and at least additionally a primary key.
- install [Schema](http://www.drupal.org/project/schema) module and goto `admin/structure/schema/inspect`. Copy + Paste + Profit

  ```
  // in yourmodule.install
  function yourmodule_schema() {
    // ... paste the $schema['your_table'] textarea stuff Schema page auto-generated for you.
    return $schema;
  }
  ```

Comment: why is my code ugly :P grrrr

Comment: It was inside a list so it needs 8 spaces not 4 ;)

Comment: No its not already defined i have to define it im going to create the table and download schema to see if i can get it to work thanks :)

Comment: @Clive I thought i put a newline or two to get out of the list .... hmmm ... thanks

Comment: Come to think of it you did, I'm not sure why it didn't break out of the list...